# Show all hashes on commit instead of range

Tags: semaphore-ci

I was trying out the notification feature on SemaphoreCI, when I ran into following "issue":
When a run is finished on semaphore it shows you a commit (hash) range instead of giving you a list of every commit that was published. I was wondering if there was any way to configure it in such a manner, that it actually shows all commit hashes.